# Postman Request Chaining by Setting Next-Token Header Variable

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script, postman-testcase

I have a GET Request that returns a fixed paginated number of results. To process all of the pages, I would need to use the available `X-Next-Token`.

I have the `X-Next-Token` set as a an empty variable in the environment.

In Postman's Tests Section, I can see that I can pull the `X-Next-Token`

##### Tests

```js
next_token = pm.response.headers.get("X-Next-Token");
console.log(next_token)
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("X-Next-Token", next_token);
console.log(pm.request.headers)
```

##### Postman Console

[image]

I've tried to this solution

```js
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("X-Next-Token", pm.response.headers.get("X-Next-Token"));
```

When the `X-Next-Token` variable is empty it seems to populate initially. But it doesn't change subsequently.

Comment: The request URL would need the variable added as a param for it to know that value `...&X-Next-Token={{X-Next-Token}}`

Comment: I have a Param key called "X-Next-Token".

Comment: And do you have the Postman variable syntax, like I have it, without that you're not going to be about to use the value that you're setting in the variable.

Comment: Yes I do. but it only seems to update once. It doesn't update a second time.